# MongoDB not equal to

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to display a query in MongoDB where a text field is not '' (blank)

```
{ 'name' : { $not : '' }}
```

However I get the error `invalid use of $not`

I've looked over the documentation but the examples they use are for complicated cases (with regexp and `$not` negating another operator).

How would I do the simple thing I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Use `$ne` --  `$not` should be followed by the standard operator:

An examples for `$ne`, which stands for not equal:

```
use test
switched to db test
db.test.insert({author : 'me', post: ""})
db.test.insert({author : 'you', post: "how to query"})
db.test.find({'post': {$ne : ""}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f68b1a7768972d396fe2268"), "author" : "you", "post" : "how to query" }
```

And now `$not`, which takes in predicate (`$ne`) and negates it (`$not`):

```
db.test.find({'post': {$not: {$ne : ""}}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f68b19c768972d396fe2267"), "author" : "me", "post" : "" }
```

Comment: For those curious `$ne` refers to "not equal".

Comment: This answer has a large number of votes, but the explanation is very unclear. What is happening in the example that has both the $not and the $ne?

Comment: so in short `$not :{ $ne` means  `$eq`, this is what you were trying to say?

Answer (score 85):

If you want to do multiple `$ne` then do

```
db.users.find({name : {$nin : ["mary", "dick", "jane"]}})
```

Answer (score 46):

Use `$ne` instead of `$not`

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/ne/#op._S_ne

```
db.collections.find({"name": {$ne: ""}});
```

Answer (score 14):

From the [Mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/):

> The `$not` operator only affects other operators and cannot check
>   fields and documents independently. So, use the `$not` operator for
>   logical disjunctions and the `$ne` operator to test the contents of
>   fields directly.

Since you are testing the field directly `$ne` is the right operator to use here.

**Edit:**

A situation where you would like to use `$not` is:

```
db.inventory.find( { price: { $not: { $gt: 1.99 } } } )
```

That would select all documents where:

- The price field value is less than or equal to 1.99 or the price
- Field does not exist

Answer (score 3):

If there is a `null` in an array and you want to avoid it:

```
db.test.find({"contain" : {$ne :[] }}).pretty()
```

Answer (score 2):

Real life example; find all but not current user:

```
var players = Players.find({ my_x: player.my_x,  my_y: player.my_y, userId: {$ne: Meteor.userId()} });
```