# Find documents where value is not null

Tags: mongodb

I have the following doc structure

```
{
    "model" : {

    },
    "_id" : ObjectId("538df963d1c3f82329000257"),
    "email" : "sam@yahoo.com",
    "name" : "sam",
    "endpointarn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:284585229836:endpoint/GCM/Positivethinking/59eb7c66-c13c-3e44-af80-0b1f4f7ea9fd",
    "devregidtoken" : "APA91bFMOBo6ZWemMAG5clKEd5VYVvbeDOM5zNXjbbl3faSE0FZt3gtJYv0hpjdWuOY-mvr-k3sCcq0dEveCM6jx5mOh1u6JEubuUmKb2zU64dn_A4gJ4pCBG7AGQJ8DnkO83Ca4wgzsoJcio9T-TtA",
    "topicsubs" : [
        {
            "topicsubid" : "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:284585229836:Wealth-ProsperityQuotes:5f3e8060-48fa-4a8e-bdc3-e9596747da1a",
            "topicname" : "Wealth-Prosperity",
            "topicno" : 0
        }
    ],
    "timecreated" : ISODate("2014-06-03T16:35:47.442Z"),
    "purchasedata" : {
        "orderid" : "111",
        "packagename" : "",
        "productid" : "",
        "purchasetime" : "",
        "purchasestate" : "",
        "developerpayload" : "",
        "purchasetoken" : ""
    },
    "ccode" : "",
    "ccodestat" : ""
}
```

I want to get all documents where purchasedata.orderid IS NOT NULL. I have tried

```
db.User.find({"purchasedata.orderid" : {$ne : ""}});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790878/mongodb-not-equal-to

Answer (score 45):

If you're checking for `null` you can use [$ne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) operator:

```
db.User.find({
   "purchasedata.orderid" : { $ne : null }
});
```

**Note:**

OP originally wanted to check that the value is not an empty string "" and not null. `null` and empty string are two different [BSON types](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/). You can use [$type](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) and [$not](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) operators to check where the value is `null` and that the key exists:

```
db.User.find({
   "purchasedata.orderid" : { 
      $not : { $type : 10 }, 
      $exists : true
   }
});
```

The `$type` operator selects documents where the value is a specific BSON type (`10` corresponds to `Null`). `$exists` will check that the key exists in the subdocument.

Answer (score 24):

You were very close. If the value is actually null, you can just use "null" instead of blank.

```
db.User.find({"purchasedata.orderid" : {$ne : null}});
```

Answer (score 16):

So this is what finally worked for me

```
db.User.find({
   "purchasedata.orderid" : {
      $exists : true,
      $ne : ""
   }
});
```

@Christian p was close so I up voted, but I think my problem was the value wasn't null but actually a empty string, also checking if the value exists is important

Comment: This does not answers the question. If you want to filter NULLs then @ChristianP's answer is the correct one.